# Delete photo in Android API v29 from background task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, storage, scoped-storage

I am trying to delete a photo in a background task. This is easily done before Android API v29:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image_id), null, null);
```

but as of Android API v29, this will throw a `RecoverableSecurityException`. This is due to the Scoped Storage requirements of Android Q. [This documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files) explains how to handle the `RecoverableSecurityException`. Here's my adaptation of it:

```
try {
    context.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, image_id), null, null);
} catch (SecurityException securityException) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RecoverableSecurityException recoverableSecurityException;
        if (securityException instanceof RecoverableSecurityException) {
            recoverableSecurityException = (RecoverableSecurityException)securityException;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(securityException.getMessage(), securityException);
        }
        IntentSender intentSender = recoverableSecurityException.getUserAction().getActionIntent().getIntentSender();

        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, image-request-code, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(securityException.getMessage(), securityException);
    }
}
```

The above code from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files) calls `startIntentSenderForResult` by itself with no activity. I had no luck getting this to work. Keep in mind that this is in a background task, so I do not have a reference to an activity. I was able to create a new activity in this background task, start that activity, and then call `startIntentSenderForResult`, but the issue here is that the activity only launches when the app is open which is not acceptable for my requirements. Since Android API v29, [strict rules](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) have been put on when an activity can be launched.

These would lead me to a solution:

- Is there a way to launch an activity in a background task without having the app open?
- Is there a way to call `startIntentSenderForResult` from my background task?

Thanks!